# Weird rendering issue: "Rendered 387/390 tiles"

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

I am experiencing rendering issues in my current Blender project (V 2.83). When I star rednering, after updating the object flags, Blender displays it has rendered 387/390 tiles (as shown below) although in the image, it is currently rendering the first 3 tiles. I have experienced this issue before and could usually solve it by simply restarting Blender, but this does not help anymore as the issue persists. Is this a bug in 2.83 or what can I change about it?
[image]

I have rendered previous frames of the animation which are almost identical without problems.

My system specs are as following:

**CPU:** Intel i7-6500U 2.5GHz

**GPU:** Nidia GeForce GTX 950M, 2GB VRAM

**RAM:** 16GB

If I let the rendering run for a while (about 10 minutes), it stops with an error message ("Launch exceeded timeout in cuCtxSynchronize")

Interestingly, when encountering this issue, my CPU is only at about 40% while when rendering normally, both my CPU and GPU are at aroun 100%! (I think this eliminates system problems as the cause of this issue).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that after restarting my computer and blender a few times, the issue disappears; it was probably just an error of blender. I would however still be interested in what causes this and how it can be avoided.